# How to stay authenticated with ms-adal-angular6?

Tags: angular, adal

I have an AuthService as wrapper for MsAdalAngular6Service. A method checks if current user is authenticated:

```
   export class AuthService {
      constructor(private adal: MsAdalAngular6Service) {}
    
   isAuthenticated() {
    return this.adal.isAuthenticated;
   }
```

If current user is inactive for some (short) time `adal.isAuthenticated` returns `false`. But I want it to return `true`.

I don't have access  to azure to change the token expiration time. So I want this application to renew the token continuously after the user has logged in at some point such that `this.adal.isAuthenticated` returns `true`:

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the ADAL we can't configure the expiration time of the token what you can do is When the adal toke is going to expiry make a `acquiretoken` request and refresh the token.
Even after refreshing the token if `adal.isAuthenticated` is not changed to ture then you need to manually set it to true for but its not the recomended way.

> We would recommend you to migrate to MSAL over ADAL as ADAL is
> Deprecrated Starting June 30th, 2020, we will no longer add new
> features to ADAL. We'll continue adding critical security fixes to
> ADAL until June 30th, 2022. After this date, your apps using ADAL will
> continue to work, but we recommend upgrading to MSAL to take advantage
> of the latest features and to stay secure.

Please choose MSAL over ADAL and here is the sample  for [angular](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/active-directory-javascript-singlepageapp-angular/active-directory-javascript-singlepageapp-angular/)  using MSAL

Please refer the link for [migration of ADAL to MSAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-migration)

Comment: Thank you Raghavendra! Maybe I try MSAL.